# Trying to store objects in a vector

Tags: c++

I'm quite new to C++ and I am trying to store objects inside a std::vector like this:

Event.h:

```
//event.h
class Event
{
public:
    Event();
    Event(std::string name);
    ~Event();
    void addVisitor(Visitor visitor);

private:
    std::vector<Visitor> m_visitors;

};
```

Event.cpp:

```
//event.cpp
Event::Event() :
    m_name("Unnamed Event")
{

}
Event::Event(std::string name) :
    m_name(name)
{

}
void Event::addVisitor(Visitor visitor)
{
    this->m_visitors.push_back(visitor);
}
void Event::listVisitors()
{
    std::vector<Visitor>::iterator it;
    for(it = this->m_visitors.begin();it != this->m_visitors.end(); ++it)
    {
        std::cout << it->getName() << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Visitor.h:

```
//visitor.h
class Visitor
{
    public:
    Visitor();
    Visitor(std::string name);
    ~Visitor();
    std::string getName() const;
    void listVisitors();

    private:
    std::string m_name;
};
```

Visitor.cpp:

```
//visitor.cpp
Visitor::Visitor() :
    m_name("John Doe")
{

}
Visitor::Visitor(std::string name) :
    m_name(name)
{

}
std::string Visitor::getName() const
{
    return m_name;
}
```

main.cpp:

```
//main.cpp
int main()
{
    Event *e1 = new Event("Whatever");
    Visitor *v1 = new Visitor("Dummy1");
    Visitor *v2 = new Visitor("Dummy2");

    e1->addVisitor(*v1);
    e1->addVisitor(*v2);
}
```

If I do it like this I would have to add a copy constructor which would make a deep copy so the object gets copied properly into the vector. I'm looking for a way around it by only storing pointers to the objects in a vector.
I already tried it with `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Visitor> > m_visitors`, but then I got some errors when calling addVisitor in main.cpp. Of course I changed the declaration of the class members accordingly.
How would an appropriate declaration of the members and the member function look like to make it work?

Comment: Does `m_visitors.push_back(visitor)` not work? I'm also a noob at C++ and I recently created a program that used almost identical syntax to accomplish the same goal, and it worked fine.

Comment: Why do you think you need to add a copy constructor? The compiler-provided one should do just fine. What you should do is get rid of all the `new`s in `main()`.

Comment: `std::string` and `std::vector` already do the right thing. You don't have to add anything. You might want to remove your use of pointers and `new` though. They are not needed.

Comment: @juanchopanza because the object gets copied from the main scope to the vector, doesnt it? I tried it like I posted, but then listVisitors only gave me empty lines (it didnt copy the value of m_name), after I added a copy constructor it worked tho. But I dont want to have to change the cctor every time I change the members of the class

Comment: If your real code looks anything like what you have in this post, then you do not need to add and copy constructors, assignment operators or destructors. The compiler provides versions of these that will copy, assign, destroy appropriately.

Comment: @juanchopanza yea, it seems to work after removing the `new`s and `*`s in main, which brings me to another question, is there a way to delete the object (call the dtor) as soon it has been copied to the vector? Now the objects exist twice, the get destroyed when I program exits.

Comment: @BETSCH: Yeah, with smart pointers. You have given yourself object ownership headaches by using `new` when you shouldn't have done. Simply don't do that. Further discussions in a chatroom, please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stylistically, if you are passing pointers, just accept pointers as the function arguments.

What's happening in the example code above is that the visitors are getting copied to become function arguments and the pointers you had are unreferenced by anything outside of the main function.

I can't speak to what the errors are that you're seeing as you didn't describe them but it probably has to do with incompatible types.

Just get rid of the `new`s because for these data structures they're unnecessary.

```
int main()
{
    Event e1("Whatever");
    Visitor v1("Dummy1");
    Visitor v2("Dummy2");

    e1.addVisitor(v1);
    e1.addVisitor(v2);
}
```

I would suggest that if you don't know how to use pointers you couldn't possibly want to store them instead (they're a hassle IMO to store in the vector when copying by value works just fine).

The compiler generated copy constructor should work just fine.

Answer (score 1):

No manual deep copy required, because you are quite correctly using `std::string`, which supports [RAII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization).

However, your `main` function has three memory leaks — there is no need to use `new` there anyway, so simply don't.

---

General rule of thumb:

**If, at any time *T*, you're thinking of introducing more pointers into your code, then you're probably going in the wrong direction.**